# Is there a plan for a featured image on meta?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, meta

I love the new layout on the main site, and I think the 'featured image' thing is a great way to encourage the community to really own the site.

However, the meta layout seems lacking, with the spot where the featured image would go as just a big 'X'.

Is there a plan to feature images here, as well?

Will we use the runner-up from the main site featured-image vote?

Or maybe a screenshot of the main site, with the featured image in it would be cool (or would that be too meta-?)

Comment: That sounds like a great idea - the 2nd place photo could go here each week? I like the idea of that

Answer (score 4):

I think the status quo (no image) is fine; the meta site gets comparatively little traffic, and I believe there's already enough work for the designers in selecting *one* featured image every week.

The designer also reasoned that the lack of image would be an important differentiator between the main site and meta; I tend to agree.

Comment: Just to add to this, I discussed this a bit last week with Jin in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14?m=121540#121540

Comment: The background colour is the main differentiator. A featured image helps bring home the fact this is a photography site.

Comment: If the amount of work required is significantly more, then that seems a semi-reasonable reason to skip it...  But... I'm having trouble imagining why it would be significantly more work to post an image (the same image, if nothing else) on the site.  Could you explain that further?  Having it differentiate makes some sense, too -- perhaps an overlay image could be made, that says META (or meta), and overlays on top of the featured image on this site?  I personally think the X feels like an accidental error (e.g. my browser is failing to load the image?), and that's disconcerting.

Comment: @chills42: If by 'last week' you meant *last year* then OK. ;-)

Comment: Well... There is a date for the post :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use the 2nd place photo from the weekly featured image poll for the Meta header image. It seems a waste just having a blank box there :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm just a weirdo, but I love the placeholder design for meta. It gives me that "you've gone behind the scenes" feel.

Comment: +1 Totally agree. The difference feels like 'rendered final' vs. 'blueprint' (if that makes sense) and it totally fits for me in theme...